# how to solve first-order linear differential equations analytically and numerically with sympy?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

How can simple linear differential equations like this one be solved in `sympy`?

```
y' + p(t)y = q(t)
```

I'm looking to solve it in two ways: symbolically (analytically) if possible, if sympy can derive the integrating factor, etc., and also a way to do it numerically so that the two can be compared. how can this be done in `sympy`? is `sympy.mpmath.odefun` the right place to look?

Comment: For symbolically solving ODE's I'd recommed you try at wolframalpha, they usually find a solution if there is one. And since you're using python, scipy has a numeric method ready: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/ode.html#dsolve) and [here](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.3/tutorial/solvers.html#solving-differential-equations) are some examples.

As for your problem, you can write your equation like:

> y' + p(t)y - q(t) = 0

and then use `dsolve()`.

```
import sympy

t = sympy.Symbol('t')

y = sympy.Function('y')(t)    
p = sympy.Function('p')(t)
q = sympy.Function('q')(t)

y_ = sympy.Derivative(y, t)

# y' + p(t)y - q(t)
sol = sympy.dsolve(y_ + p*y - q, y)

print(sol)
```

---

**Solution as function**

*(Note : This is a quick solution i came up with by reading the documentation. I am not experienced with `sympy`. There might be much better ways to do the following.)*

Suppose you want to solve `y' = y`.

```
from sympy import *

t = symbols('t')

y = Function('y')(t)
y_ = Derivative(y, t)

sol = dsolve(y_ - y, y)
```

We did the same as previously. Now, to use the second part of the `sol`, we use `.args[1]`. Then we create a function `f(t_)` and substitute the t value using [`subs()`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.3/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution).

```
def f(t_): 
    return sol.args[1].subs([(t, t_)])

print(sol)
print(f(0))
```